# Wrong return value pattern

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Community!

I'm new in Elixir and faced one problem.
I'm making an API on the Phoenix and stick to one pattern:

- `{:ok, some_data}` on success
- `{:error, some_data}` on error.

My controller requested the domain:

```
with {:ok, some_data} <- Organisation.create(...) do

end
```

The domain, in turn, requests to some service:

```
with {:ok, service_data} when length(service_data) == 0 <- SomeService.get(...) do
    {:ok, [1, 2, 3]} # Some other LIST data
end
```

So, if `when length(service_data) == 0` becomes `True`, then service will return
`{:ok, [1, 2, 3]}`, but if it `False`, then service will return `{:ok, service_data}` - which is unacceptable!

What can I do in such a situation? Are there any best practices.

P.S. Filtering returns using `case` is not an option, since both returns are `{:ok, []}`.

Comment: What do you want the function to return when `length(service_data) > 0`?

Comment: The question says it'll return `{:ok, [1, 2, 3]}` when list is empty. You want the same for non-empty list?

Comment: Could you add the expected input/output for each case to the question?

Comment: if ```length(service_data) = 0``` will return ```{:ok, [1, 2, 3]}```
if ```length(service_data) > 0``` will return some error, I think, or it's impossible?

Comment: I`d like to use ```with do end``` construction, because "create" logic consists of several actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> P.S. Filtering returns using case is not an option, since both returns are {:ok, []}.

Not sure what you mean by that, but this really is suited for `case` with a list pattern:

```
case SomeService.get(...) do
  {:ok, []} -> {:ok, [1, 2, 3]}
  {:ok, _} -> {:error, "not an empty list"}
  error -> error
end
```

The first clause matches the empty list, so the second one will match non-empty lists. If neither match, we return the value we got.